# Live connection between ArGIS Online and Google Docs Spreadsheet?

Tags: arcgis-online, google-docs

I want to make a join in ArcGIS Online: From a spreadsheet with names (visitors to an exhibition) to polygons (containing that name).
I succeed to make that in ArcGIS Online: but there is no live connection.

Has anyone already done this?

Do I really need Zapier to make that connection?

We have an organisational account on ArcGIS Online

I have already tried several things: 
add an item from cloud drive
within an item: add a layer from the web (.csv spreadsheet)

There is no need to change that spreadsheet from within ArcGIS Online.

Comment: Zapier is still in beta concerning this connection. This is only a solution if the spreadsheet contains XY-coordinates or addresses. This is not the case in my spreadsheet. I just want to make a join between two fields.

Answer (score 0):

For live update of data you can use Survey123, when all the entries are over or when you want spreadsheet you can export CVS and your data is updated real-time on the map.